# Maintain Scroll Position with response.redirect function

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have one main page in my asp.net website.

In that page i have used gridview with hyperlinkfield.

on click of any of hyperlink, application will redirecting to detailed page.

on coming back to main page i want to hold scroll position instead of i am getting top of page.

i have tried maintainscrollposition script but its not working.

i also have used master page.

i have used button on detailed page and onclick i have used response.redirect.

How can i maintain my scroll position in this scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are leaving the page and coming back, you cannot store in data in javascript or the `ViewState`. This leaves you with two options:

Save the scroll position in a session variable. You will have to use a hidden field to send a javascript variable to the server to save it.

You could also use a cookie with an appropriate expiry time to remember the scroll position. Using a cookie allows for a pure javascript solution.

Using a cookie is a simpler and better option in my opinion.